# How to convert ipv4 strings to varbinary in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, ip-address, varbinary, mybb

I have a mysql database table that contains ipv4 addresses in a varchar(15) column, and I am trying to insert them into another table that has ip addresses in a varbinary(16) column.  How do I do this with just MySQL, no php?

I have tried

```
CAST(u.U_RegIP AS varbinary(16)) AS regip
```

This does not work; it says that there is an error in my syntax.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

THE issue is with varbinary  you should convert it to binary instead of varbinary

-------example --------

```
mysql> select CONVERT("123", VARCHAR(100));
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR(100))' at line 1
```

if i try to convert it to varchar  i get same issue

```
mysql> select CONVERT("123", CHAR(100));
+---------------------------+
| CONVERT("123", CHAR(100)) |
+---------------------------+
| 123                       |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```